# Многоуровненый запрос с функцией COUNT в SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

В базе данных 3 связанные таблицы:

```
dbo.STUDENT (столбцы ID_Student, Stname, Birthday, Averagemark, Bursary, ID_Group, Bonus, ID_City) 

dbo.UGROUP (столбцы ID_Group, Gname, ID_Univercity) 

dbo.UNIVERSITY (столбцы ID_University, Uname, Adress, ID_City).
```

Нужно посчитать студентов в каждом университете. Понимаю, что нужно создать многоуровневый запрос с функцией `COUNT`, но не соображу, как посчитать в двух таблицах сразу.

Answer (score 0):

Не надо здесь многоуровневый запрос. Обычных джойнов хватит:

```
select u.Uname, count(*)
from university u
join ugroup g on (g.ID_University = u.ID_University)
join student s on (d.ID_Group = s.ID_Group)
group by u.Uname
```